# Returning a new set of array using map method

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reactjs

How do I return a new set of array using `map` based on 2 conditions:

- The array length should not be 0
- role should be moderator

This is my original response looks like

[image]

React function which maps the response

```
_getList(memberships) {
    const items = memberships.map((membership) => {
        return (
            <RadioButton
                value={membership.forum.slug}
                label={membership.forum.title} />
        );
    });

    return(
        <RadioButtonGroup>
            {items}
        </RadioButtonGroup>
    );
}
```

In my render function I am checking if the length is not 0

```
const renderedList = this._getList(UserStore.getState().memberships.length !== 0);
```

How should I add another check that the new array returned should only contains the data with `role === moderator`

Comment: Which array length should not be zero?

Comment: memberships object length. I have edited my question and I forgot to add `.length`, which is corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using filter

```
_getList(memberships) {
    const items = (memberships.filter(membership => membership.role === 'moderator') || []).map((membership) => {
        return (
            <RadioButton
                value={membership.forum.slug}
                label={membership.forum.title} />
        );
    });

    if(items.length === 0) return null;

    return(
        <RadioButtonGroup>
            {items}
        </RadioButtonGroup>
    );
}
```

then you could do this:

```
const renderedList = this._getList(UserStore.getState().memberships);

if(renderedList) {
    this.renderSomething();
} else {
    this.renderSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to take a look at the [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of the Array API.

```
const items = memberships
    .filter(item => item.role === 'moderator')
    .map((membership) => {
        return (
            <RadioButton
                value={membership.forum.slug}
                label={membership.forum.title} />
        );
    })
```

`.filter` will iterate through all member of the array and return a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function. If the `memberships` array is empty, it'll simple return an empty array.

This assumes that the `memberships` property always is an array. Either an array with values in it, or an empty array (`[]`). If the `memberships` property can be missing, you still need to add a check such as your `renderedList` one.

Comment: Thanks. `memberships` property is either an empty array or it contains data so I don't have to worry about another check.